# Set-ItemProperty message when importing virtualenvwrapper

Tags: python, powershell, virtualenvwrapper

Here is the message that I get. For what it's worth, I opened my registry and noticed that there is no `2.7` folder, `PythonCore` leads straight into `InstallPath` . Any ideas?

```
Set-ItemProperty : Cannot find path 'HKCU:\Software\Python\PythonCore\2.7\InstallPath' because it does not exist.
At C:\Users\...\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\virtualenvwrapper\win.psm1:127 char:21
+     set-itemproperty <<<<  -path "HKCU:/Software/Python/PythonCore/$pyVer/InstallPath" -name "(default)" -value $pyBa
se
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (HKCU:\Software\...2.7\InstallPath:String) [Set-ItemProperty], ItemNotFo
   undException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PathNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.SetItemPropertyCommand

Set-ItemProperty : Cannot find path 'HKCU:\Software\Python\PythonCore\2.7\PythonPath' because it does not exist.
At C:\Users\...\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\virtualenvwrapper\win.psm1:128 char:21
+     set-itemproperty <<<<  -path "HKCU:/Software/Python/PythonCore/$pyVer/PythonPath" -name "(default)" -value "$pyBa
se\Lib;$pyBase\DLLs;$pyBase\Lib\lib-tk"
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (HKCU:\Software\...\2.7\PythonPath:String) [Set-ItemProperty], ItemNotFo
   undException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PathNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.SetItemPropertyCommand
```

Comment: Any luck solving this? I'm Having the same issue.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I had the Same issue, googled around and managed to solve the solution. here's what I came across.

> Python appears to update the registry under HKEY_CURRENT_USER and some install look for python under HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE.

Useful Sources I came across

- [Source 1](http://avaminzhang.wordpress.com/2011/11/24/python-version-2-7-required-which-was-not-found-in-the-registry/#comment-745)
- [Python Version 2.7 required which was not found in the registry](http://blog.eddsn.com/2012/01/python-version-2-7-required-which-was-not-found-in-the-registry/)
- [Restoring Your Python Registry in Windows](http://ericsilva.org/2012/10/11/restoring-your-python-registry-in-windows/)

So assuming your python installation is at `C:\python27`

From this [Restoring Your Python Registry in Windows](http://ericsilva.org/2012/10/11/restoring-your-python-registry-in-windows/) article -

1. Copied from lines `17 - 21`,

> [HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Python\Pythoncore\2.7\InstallPath]
>   @="C:\python27"
>   [HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Python\Pythoncore\2.7\PythonPath]
>   @="C:\python27;C:\python27\Lib\;C:\python27\DLLs\"
>
> Paste them to a text file.
>
> Rename it to `fix_python.reg` or anything you wish :)
>
> Double-click the file, and follow the prompts to load the new values into the Windows Registry.
>
> May not be the best way. But it worked fine for me.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks! Worked for me. Don't forget to include: "Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00"

Answer (score 1):

I'm using Windows 10 and had to add it manually. Here's a export of the modification that I made:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Python]

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Python\PythonCore]

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Python\PythonCore\2.7]

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Python\PythonCore\2.7\InstallPath]
@="C:\\python27"

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Python\PythonCore\2.7\PythonPath]
@="C:\\python27;C:\\python27\\Lib\\;C:\\python27\\DLLs\\"
```